# For specific number of times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to do something like this in my HTML:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

However rather than do it for every entry I only want the first 6 items in the model. Does anyone know the syntax?  Have tried a few with no sucess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `Take` LINQ method

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(6))
```

don't forget to add namespace `System.Linq` in your view

Comment: Just to add, @NickP, you may want to add an OrderBy in case there is a sort order of some sort that you want to get the items out of the model.

Comment: @vonv. yes sure, but he stated explicitly `I only want the first 6 items in the model`

Comment: right I was just suggesting as maybe the OP also wants a sorted items (before) the take. I like your answer btw (and upvoted it) that's why I was expanding on it rather than create a new answer.

Comment: @vonv. thanks. I just assume OP has an ordered sequence of items in the `Model`, that's why he stated about only first items. Anyway, I don't like to much logic inside my views.

Comment: yeah I think I was not thinking straight there. Each time I answer someone who ask about a view. I always tell them to move the logic into the controller. And yet here I'm suggesting the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `for` loop.

e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.Take<TSource> Method`: Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

Eg.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(5)) {
```

Refer:

[Enumerable.Take Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)